# How to fix bootstrap sections from running together on sm screen?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

My website looks great on my laptop, however, when I adjust down to a small screen, the text from my first section is running on into the lower section. Everything else is looking great, just the "run on" onto the next section. I am new to bootstrap so I am not understanding. Ive tried adding new sections tags, new divs, still can't seem to find the problem.

```
<body>
    <nav id="navShadow" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark effect">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#education">Education</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>


        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <!--HEAD SECTION -->
        <section class="head">
            <header id="home-section">
                <div class="dark-overlay">
                    <div class="home-inner">
                        <div class="container">

                            <div class="row">



                                <div class="col-me-3 hidden-sm-down">
                                    <div class="grow">

                                        <img class="profile-pic" src="./img/portrait.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-9 main-col">

                                    <h1 class="mb-2">About Me</h1>

                                    <p class="mt-4">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                                        laudantium,
                                        totam rem aperiam,
                                        eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                                        Nemo enim ipsam
                                        voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos
                                        qui ratione
                                        voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
                                        consectetur, adipisci velit,
                                        sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
                                        voluptatem.
                                        Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam.
                                    </p>
                                    <ul class="social">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div> <!-- end row -->

                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    </section>


    <!-- Education -->

    <section id="education">
        <div class="education">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row education justify-content-center">



                    <h1><span>Education</span></h1>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <h3>University of Life</h3>
                        <p class="info">Master in Field <span>&bull;</span> <em class="date">April 2017</em></p>

                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                            massa.
                            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                            felis,
                            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                            Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
                            mollis pretium.
                        </p>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <h3>University of Life</h3>
                        <p class="info">Master in Test <span>&bull;</span> <em class="date">march 2007</em></p>

                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                            massa.
                            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                            felis,
                            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                            Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
                            mollis pretium.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3">

                        <img src="./img/educationimg.jpg" alt="" class="eduimg">



                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
        </div> <!-- End Education -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-3">
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background:$bg-color;
    color: $font-color;
    font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive;


}

#home-section{
    background: url('../img/profilepic.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-color: $dark-overlay;
    min-height: 575px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s; 
      animation-iteration-count: 1; 
      animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    font-size: 25px;

    .dark-overlay{
      background-color: $dark-overlay;
      position: absolute;
      top: 54px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      //height: 100%;
      min-height: 575px;
  }
  .main-col { padding-right: 5%; }

    .profile-pic{
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: #e08cb3 2px solid;


      }
    //Media in the Home Section
.home-inner{
  padding-top: 125px;

}



}



// FA-Icons
.social {
  margin: 24px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.social li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

header .social li a { color: #fff; }
header .social li a:hover { color: #e08cb3; }


//Navbar

.navbar {
    background: #e08cb3;

}


.card {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e08cb3;

}


.education{
  margin-top: 5%;
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s; 
      animation-iteration-count: 1; 
      animation-fill-mode: forwards; 

  .eduimg{
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 240px;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%
  }


}
```

Comment: I am not experiencing this issue. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I am testing in Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot please?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 works fine in all browsers, even in IE10/IE11.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at your css, the structure of your html is not correct. If I format your html, it looks like this code below. I have commented some (maybe not all) structure bugs.

```
<!--head section -->
<section class="head"> <!-- add row to class (parent is container) -->
  <header id="home-section">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="home-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-me-3 hidden-sm-down"> <!-- col-md-3 -->
              <div class="grow">
                <img class="profile-pic" src="./img/portrait.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 main-col">
              <h1 class="mb-2">About Me</h1>
              <p class="mt-4">Some text</p>
              <ul class="social">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end container -->
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- NO starting div -->
  </header>
</section>

<!-- Education -->
<section id="education"> <!-- add class="row" (parent is container) -->
  <div class="education">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row education justify-content-center">
        <h1><span>Education</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
          <h3>University of Life</h3>
          <p>Some text</p>
          <h3>University of Life</h3>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <img src="./img/educationimg.jpg" alt="" class="eduimg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  </div> <!-- NO starting div -->
  </div> <!-- NO starting div -->
  </div> <!-- NO starting div -->
</section>
```

Please look at the Bootstrap 4 grid examples how to use container, row, and col-x-y. It is good practice to build the stucture with one line text on each text-block and then test it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try this in .css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
     /*----There you can implement your sections----*/
     /*----Example:----*/
     .card{
          height: 50%;
          width: 50%;
     }
}
```

When use this code,screen which has max-width or less than 768px uses this code.
Check it maybe help you.